# c++ remove and rename commands

Tags: android, c++

I am using aide and cppdroid for android to code in c++. I'm having some trouble with the file rename and remove commands. My guess is you can't do this. I have user input and don't know what they will type in so I need a variable or string to input for the path name of the file.

```
remove("/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/" + output2 + ".txt");             

rename("/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/temp.txt","/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/" + output2 + ".txt");
```

Is the code I used and it has an error. Is there some other way I can write this so I can add the output2 to locate the file?

Error is:

> NDK:cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'char const*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(char const*)'

Answer (score 0):

> NDK:cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'char const*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(char const*)'

You're function is expecting an array of characters, but you're passing it a string object. You need to call `.c_str()` on your string object.

[std::basic_string::c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

So the `"/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/" + output2 + ".txt"` needs to be an array of characters itself.

One way to achieve this would be to store it as a string, then pass the `c_str()` into the function.

```
std::string loc{"/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/" + output2 + ".txt"};

remove(loc.c_str());
```

Comment: This will crash (or worse).

Comment: Is it because I am appending a c string to a string literal and just now catching it, or am I missing something?

Comment: Adding `const char *`'s together is never a good idea.  See my duplicate link in the comments to the question to see how it should be done.

Comment: Basically, if you add some `( )` it will be correct.

Comment: Figured that was it. I fixed my answer to match @NathanOliver

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what worked with no errors.

```
std::string loc ("/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/" + output2 + ".txt");
remove(loc.c_str());
std::string loc1("/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/temp.txt");
std::string loc2("/storage/emulated/0/MyGame/MyHackGame/jni/gameFiles/" + output2 + ".txt");
rename(loc1.c_str() , loc2.c_str());
```